# EditText Problem

Tags: android

how to do this effect? :)

prompt, enter the value judgments EditText correct

thanks

link : [effect image](http://nikonizer.yfrog.com/Himg714/scaled.php?tn=0&server=714&filename=devicez.png&xsize=640&ysize=640)

Comment: @ADWings: Please describe the effect so that if the link breaks people will still be able to understand what the question is about

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using PopupWindow. You can place pop up window at any place you want in the screen.

Comment: yes,this is can using PopupWindow.but there is a simpler approach